# Chat in Yii2 is not working

Tags: yii2, chat

Good day. I would like to add this https://github.com/sintret/yii2-chat-adminlte chat in yii2 to my project. I followed instructions but it's not working. help me please.

I installed it via composer.

```
"sintret/yii2-chat-adminlte": "dev-master"
```

Create table

```
CREATE TABLE `chat` (
  `id` INT(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `userId` INT(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `message` TEXT,
  `updateDate` TIMESTAMP NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP ON UPDATE CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=INNODB;
```

Add in Controller

```
public function actionSendChat() {
    $message = $_POST['message'];
    if ($message) {
        $model = new Chat;
        $model -> message = $message;
        if ($model -> save()) {
            echo ChatRoom::data();
        } else {
            print_r($model -> getErrors());
            exit(0);
        }
    }
}
```

And in view

```
 <?php
            echo \sintret\chat\ChatRoom::widget([
                    'url' => \yii\helpers\Url::to(['/chat/send-chat']),
                    'userModel'=>  \app\modules\user\models\User::className(),
                    'userField'=>'avatarImage'
                ]
            );
            ?>
```

model User have avatarImage field.

I changed `$message = $_POST['message'];` to `$message = \Yii::$app->request-‌​>post('message');`
Because when i tried to open `sendChat.php` there was a problem

```
Undefined index: message
```

The problem with undefined message disappered, but view form sendChat.php was empty.

After that i changed actionSendChat like this

```
    public function actionSendChat() {
//        $message = $_POST['message'];
        $message = \Yii::$app->request->post('message');
        if ($message) {
            $model = new Chat;
            $model -> message = $message;
            if ($model -> save()) {
                echo ChatRoom::data();
            } else {
                print_r($model -> getErrors());
                exit(0);
            }
        }
        return $this -> render('sendChat',
            ['model' => $message]
            );
    }
```

And it's shows chat like below.
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

When i equated variable $message from Controller to string 'Hello'; and then refreshed  view form `sendChat.php` this message had inserted in DB and then appeared in view form

[image]

Help me please. How can i fix this?

Comment: Undefined index: message, because of you don`t pass message parameter.

Comment: @Shaig Khaligli how can i fix this?

Comment: By passing message parameter.